# Which of the following is a better solution? It's about using a list to store RGB values

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I want to use a singly-linked list to store an image consisting of RGB pixels. The node in the list should contain the value of RGB and its consecutively occurring times. For example, I have an image including 4 pixels and their (R,G,B) values are (8,2,5),(8,2,6),(8,7,6) and (8,7,9) respectively. In this situation, if using a singly-linked list to store them more compactly, the nodes should store the following information:
red needs one node: value 8, repetition times 4(because there are four consecutive 8).
green needs two nodes: 1st node(value:2, repetition 2), 2nd node(value:7,repetition 2)
blue needs three nodes: 1st node(value 5, repetition 1), 2nd node(value:6,repetition 2) 3rd node(value 8,repetition 1)

I wonder which of the following is better:

1.Using one Singly-linked list which contains 3 heads to point to R,G and B nodes respectively. That means storing R,G and B are stored in 3 different sequence of nodes.

2.Using one Singly-linked list which contains only 1 head, but the content of nodes has to be an array to store RGB. That means R,G,and B are combined as an array of 3 elements(R,G,B) and the arrays are stored in one single sequence of nodes.

I think the first solution is easier to realize, but it seems to require more space(creating more nodes). The second may have a potential problem since the number of nodes needed for R, G and B is not the same.

Comment: I would use a three dimentional array for performance reason like count[r][g][b] = x;  I did not completely understand your requirement though like what you exactly mean by consecutively occurring times.

Comment: What are `heads`? Can you make the Node class for the two different cases. Also what is your criteria? Why do you mention the frequency information? eg. What about 844.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain my question  clearly before. For 844, two nodes are needed, the 1st node should contain (8,1) for value 8 and repetition times 1 respectively. And 2nd node should be (4,2) for value 4 and repetition 2.

Comment: @Satish Thanks for your answer. Sorry I didn't explain clearly my question. Now I have updated it to make it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to compress an image, you should really consider standard compression techniques. I have a feeling compressing and decompressing an image in the manner will not be very effecient.